# With Azure should i store my static shared JS and images files in the package release or in a blob?

Tags: azure, blob

Speed and cost in mind.
Say I have a few JS and images files shared for multiple websites. that is not huge images files, this is only few static files like PNG sprites and common JS files.
I'm kind of lost on the choice :
- Should i keep it in my webpackage to release in Azure ?
- Or should i put these in blobs ?

The things I don't know is if i have a lot of hits on the blob solution, it might cost more than the hits on the IIS level of the package ?
Right, wrong ?

Edit : I realize storing JS files on the blob won't deliver it gziped ?

Answer (score 0):

No need for the blobs that I can see.  The database round trip isn't adding value.  I'd just put the static content on the web server and let it serve it up.  Let the web server handle compressing the bytes on the wire for those cases where the client indicates that they can handle GZIP compression.

Answer (score 0):

Will your JS and image files be modified often? If so, putting them into the service package would mean that every time you want to update those files, you will have to recompile the service package and redeploy your instance. If you find yourself needing to update often, this will become cumbersome. From a speed perspective, you're not going to see too much of a difference between service them files up from the blogs or serving them up from the web role (assuming the files are in fact not huge). Last but not least, from a cost perspective, if you look at the cost of blob storage ($0.15 per GB stored per month, $0.01 per 10,000 storage transactions), its really not much. Your site would have to have a lot of traffic for the cost to become significant.